# Foreach data list from array - incrementing numbers

Tags: php, arrays, json, rest, api

I am trying to create a option list from a JSON decoded API link.
So far I have the access to the API sorted, all the data I need stored in a single variable and can extract data from the variable using

```
 print_r($result[0]["ORGANISATION_NAME"]);

 print_r($result[1]["ORGANISATION_NAME"]);
```

This will give me two different Organisation names from the array.

What I would like to do is put this in an alphabetical drop down menu, but for some reason I cannot for the life of me get foreach to work. All we need to do is increment the 0,1,2,3 etc to the number of records stored in the database.

I have no idea on how to do that !

Comment: Please show us what you have tried as far as `foreach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question as asked:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
        print_r($result[$i]["ORGANISATION_NAME"]);
    }
}
```

However, why not just another `foreach`?

EDIT:

Updating based off of new info:

Assuming `$result` is your DB result here is your new code:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    print_r($row['ORGANISATION_NAME']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I am not to familiar with the foreach function, probably why I am having trouble with it. Trying to learn PHP again after never really learning it..I am still getting an error though, which is what was happening before                   
Notice: Undefined variable: results in C:\xampp\htdocs\database\get4.php on line 50

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\database\get4.php on line 50                                                                         Line 50 is the first line of the Foreach function

Comment: This is the origin of the $result variable - $context = stream_context_create($opts);
$json = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$result = json_decode($json, true);
if(json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE){
    return null;
}

Comment: Thanks, not 100% on how to implement it, but playing with the original, I now get an undefined index, probably referring to the "ORGANISATION_NAME", The counter appears to be working though. I wish I could share the array data with you so you knew what it looks like.

Comment: Nope, my problem. I'm an idiot. Updated with actual working code.

Answer (score 0):

I think a couple of sensible steps of data preparation will help to simplify this task for you.

1. Isolate the desired column of data and create a new 1-dimensional array of organization names.
2. Sort the names alphabetically.

Then you can use a simple foreach loop to generate the html select field.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bDSRJ))

```
$result = [
    ["ORGANISATION_NAME" => "B Name"],
    ["ORGANISATION_NAME" => "D Name"],
    ["ORGANISATION_NAME" => "C Name"],
    ["ORGANISATION_NAME" => "A Name"]
];

echo "Proof of correct structure: {$result[1]["ORGANISATION_NAME"]}\n";

$org_names = array_column($result, "ORGANISATION_NAME");

sort($org_names);

var_export($org_names);  // display alphabetized array

echo "\n---\n";

echo "<select name=\"orgs\">";
foreach ($org_names as $org) {
    echo "<option>$org</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Output:

```
Proof of correct structure: D Name
array (
  0 => 'A Name',
  1 => 'B Name',
  2 => 'C Name',
  3 => 'D Name',
)
---
<select name="orgs">
    <option>A Name</option>
    <option>B Name</option>
    <option>C Name</option>
    <option>D Name</option>
</select>
```